# Make a website layout and content fix with any size of our monitor

Tags: html, css, web

How to make a website layout and website content fix when the size of our monitor changes???Just like from 15" monitor change to 21" monitor...all of the content in website doesn't change.
Sometimes when we see our website in another laptop with different monitor size, the content of the website fall apart.

I make an application in which I use div tag but one problem is that in other or big resolution monitors it shows different view and some other monitors show another view of my Website. So how can I fix the view for all the monitor resolution.

Comment: You have to use percents while writing styles imho.

Answer (score 0):

I think media queries sound like they could be your saviour. You can use them to create a responsive site - from mobile to tablet to desktop etc. With media queries you can target different resolutions and fix/sort/adapt your design using CSS to make the best viewing experience for the user. This approach would be called Responsive Web Design, which is quite the buzzword(s) at the moment.

Some quick links for info:

[Link 1](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)

[Link 2](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries/)

If you feel like buying a book/e-book, I would recommend:

[Responsive Web Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design)

Answer (score 0):

Well come to the world of responsive web design, Your perfect solution lies in [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

You need to explore Media Queries, Responsive Images as well.